# Converting a comma separated filed to a matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

I have a comma separated file in the format:

```
Col1Name,Col1Val1,Col1Val2,Col1Val3,...Col1ValN,Col2Name,Col2Val1,...Col2ValN,...,ColMName,ColMVal1,...,ColMValN
```

My question is, how can I convert this file into something Matlab can treat as a matrix, and how would I go about using this matrix in a file? I supposed I could some scripting language to format the file into matlab matrix format and copy it, but the file is rather large (~7mb).

Thanks!

Sorry for the edit:

The file format is:

```
Col1Name;Col2Name;Col3Name;...;ColNName
Col1Val1;Col2Val2;Col3Val3;...;ColNVal1
...
Col1ValM;Col2ValM;Col3ValM;...;VolNValM
```

Here is some actual data:

```
Press;Temp.;CondF;Cond20;O2%;O2ppm;pH;NO3;Chl(a);PhycoEr;PhycoCy;PAR;DATE;TIME;excel.date;date.time
0.96;20.011;432.1;431.9;125.1;11.34;8.999;134;9.2;2.53;1.85;16.302;08.06.2011;12:01:52;40702;40702.0.5
1;20.011;433;432.8;125;11.34;9;133.7;8.19;3.32;2.02;17.06;08.06.2011;12:01:54;40702;40702.0.5
1.1;20.012;432.7;432.4;125.1;11.34;9;133.8;8.35;2.13;2.2;19.007;08.06.2011;12:01:55;40702;40702.0.5
1.2;20.012;432.8;432.5;125.2;11.35;9.001;133.8;8.45;2.95;1.95;21.054;08.06.2011;12:01:56;40702;40702.0.5
1.3;20.012;432.7;432.4;125.4;11.37;9.002;133.7;8.62;3.17;1.87;22.934;08.06.2011;12:01:57;40702;40702.0.5
1.4;20.007;432.1;431.9;125.2;11.35;9.003;133.7;9.48;4.17;1.6;24.828;08.06.2011;12:01:58;40702;40702.0.5
1.5;19.997;432.3;432.2;124.9;11.33;9.003;133.8;8.5;3.84;1.79;27.327;08.06.2011;12:01:59;40702;40702.0.5
1.6;20;432.8;432.6;124.5;11.29;9.003;133.6;8.57;3.22;1.86;30.259;08.06.2011;12:02:00;40702;40702.0.5
1.7;19.99;431.9;431.9;124.4;11.28;9.002;133.6;8.79;3.7;1.81;35.152;08.06.2011;12:02:02;40702;40702.0.5
1.8;19.994;432.1;432.1;124.4;11.28;9.002;133.6;8.58;3.41;1.84;39.098;08.06.2011;12:02:03;40702;40702.0.5
1.9;19.993;433;432.9;124.6;11.3;9.002;133.6;8.59;3.45;5.53;45.488;08.06.2011;12:02:04;40702;40702.0.5
2;19.994;433;432.9;124.8;11.32;9.002;133.5;8.6;2.76;1.99;50.646;08.06.2011;12:02:05;40702;40702.0.5
```

Comment: do you the number of columns/rows ahead of time? also please post a couple of lines of your actual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know number of rows and columns up front, you can't use previous solution.  Use this instead.

7 Mb is not large, it is small.  This is the 21st century.

To read in to a matlab matrix:

```
    text = fileread('file.name'); % a string with the entire file contents in it.  7 Mb is no big deal.
    NAMES = {}; % we'll record column names here
    VALUES = []; % this will be the matrix of values

    while text(end) = ','
        text(end)=[]; % elimnate any trailing commas
    end

    commas = find(text==','); % Index all the commas
    commas = [0;commas(:);length(commas)+1] % put fake commas before and after text to simplify loop

    col = 0; % which column are we in

    I = 1;
    while I<length(commas) 
        txt = text(commas(I)+1:commas(I+1)-1);
        I = I+1;
        num = str2double(txt);
        if isnan(num) % this means it must be a column name
            NAMES{end+1,1} = txt;
            col = col+1; % can you believe Matlab doesn't support col++ ???
            row = 1; % back to the top at each new column
            continue % we have dealt with this txt, its not a num so ... next
        end

        % if we made it here we have a number
        VALUES(row,col) = num;
    end
```

Then you can save your matlab matrix `VALUES` and also the header names if you want them in matlab format `NAMES` into matlab format file

```
    save('mymatrix.mat','VALUES','NAMES'); % saves matrix and column names to .mat file
```

You get stuff back in to matlab when you want it from the file by:

```
    load mymatrix.mat; % loads VALUES and NAMES from .mat file
```

---

Some limitations:

You can't use commas in your column header names.

You cannot "name" a column something like "898.2" or anything which can be read as a double number, it will be read in as a number.

If your columns have different lengths, the shorter ones will be padded with zeros to the length of the longest column.

That's all I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I will accept the answer once I get a chance to try it out, which will probably be tomorrow. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey I really appreciate your answer. Unfortunately I wrote the above from work, and I got the format wrong. I have updated with the format. I'm sure I can adapt you code to use the new format, but I had some questions about Matlab syntax (this is my first time using Matlab).

1) Why are NAMES and VALUES capitalized. Is this convention?

2) Where is `end` declared, as in `text(end)`

3) Can you better explain the line `commas = [0;commas(:);length(commas)+1]`

4) How can I get the number of lines in the file?

Thanks again for your help. I am totally lost with this stuff.

Comment: Use the `helpwin` command from the prompt and then start searching on some of these terms you are interested in.  1) NAMES and VALUES are capitalized because I felt like it.  It also lowers the chances of collision with a matlab predifined function which by convention are all lower case.  2) `end` always refers to the last element in an array index when used in the index.  You can even get the middle element with something like A(round(end)/2).

Comment: 3) I have appended an index value of 0 to the front and length(commas)+1 to the back "as if" there were invisible commas to start and end the file.  This way I don't have to specially handle the first and last text fields in the loop.  4) You can use `newlines=find(text==char(10));` to find all the end of line markers in your file, and use that a lot like I use commas.

Comment: I'm really new to Matlab, but it seems silly that you need to use `char(10)` instead of `'\n'`. Oh well. I'm slowly making progress on getting this working. It is certainly a learning experience.

Comment: I'm not really sure about your use of the variable `I`. I never see it assigned a value. Am I missing something?

Comment: Fixed the I thing, oops.  '\n' is a 2-long char array with '\' followed by 'n'.  char(10) is a one-long char array with newline.  you could use `nl=sprintf('\n')` to generate a single newline character.